# How to add a .sql file to sqlite db in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, xcode4.2

I am writing a offline iPhone app in which I need to read and display from a database which consists of a few number of tables. The tables have over 100k entries in it, so it is almost impossible to enter it all individually. I have downloaded the `.sql` file of the entire db. Now how can I import the db as such into sqlite/Xcode so that I can readily start accessing the data in it??
Edit: I have seen that when using a database, the file extension that is used is a `.db` file. Is there anyway I can convert the `.sql` file to a `.db` file. And if I can do that, can I simply access the `.db` file by placing it in the project directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have created the .sqlite file and have the tables in it,Then add the .sqlite file into xcode like just drag from desktop into your bundle(Resources).And then use NSFileManager to access the sqlite file.You need to write methods for createdatabase and initialize database and also you can see the sqlite file in your documents folder/simulator folder.

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    NSLog(@"Checking for database file");
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ihaikudb.sql"];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

    NSLog(@"If needed, bundled default DB is at: %@",defaultDBPath);

    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"Database didn't exist... Copying default from resource dir");
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success) 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Database must have existed at the following path: %@", dbPath);
    }
    NSLog(@"Done checking for db file");
}
```

Comment: We use to read database from a `.db` file right? Rather, I have a `.sql` file with me, not `.sqlite`

Comment: no problem you just drag and drop the file into your folder and start working.the type of file extension doesn't matter.If you have copy then drag and drop into your workng folder is called sandboxing.

Comment: My doubt is, the `.sql` file actually has the commands to create the database and the tables and to insert the values into the tables. How is it possible to access values from such a file by using sql commands?

Comment: It is the same as .sqlite and .sql are same

Comment: how to get [self getDBPath] ?

Comment: '[self getDBPath]' shows error. How to overcome it?