# How to access local database

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I need to create a copy of our database on my local machine.

Then I need to link the local database to the app in Config.plist file.

The Config.plist file has all of the paths to connect to a data source.

How to do this work ? any help is appreciated.

I got .sql file to download on my system local system. then to use in my code. 
I am struck and no idea how to use it?
please need help in solving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in iphone applications you can use only sqlite database

Comment: Thank you Indrajeet Senger, Is there any way to convert .sql file to .sqlite

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691122/how-to-add-a-sql-file-to-sqlite-db-in-xcode